# Varios Count numa sql Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho 2 tabelas, uma chamados e outra cliente, preciso retornar quantos chamados do cliente teve no mes corrente, mes passado e mes retrasado, tentei usando o union, ele me retornou normalmente, mas, só consigo fazer um count.

```
  SELECT  
  COUNT(*) AS total_chamado,
  from chamado, cliente
  where
     chamado.id_cliente = cliente.id AND
  GROUP BY chamado.id_cliente
  union
  (
  SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total_chamado_passado,
  from chamado, cliente
  where
     chamado.id_cliente = cliente.id AND
     chamado.data_atendimento  BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month AND CURDATE()
  GROUP BY chamado.id_cliente
  )
```

Comment: Vc pode usar IF e SUM na sua lista de campos. Tipo SUM(IF(campo_para_testar = 2, 1, 0)) AS numero_resultado
e assim calcular varios reslutados

Answer (score 1):

A maneira que eu faço é criar subselects com join para cada totalizador que eu preciso e depois agrupo tudo num select mais externo. No seu caso, ficaria assim:

```
SELECT cli.id_cliente, total_chamado.total_chamado, total_chamado_passado.total_chamado_passado 
FROM cliente cli
INNER JOIN (SELECT  cliente.id_cliente, COUNT(*) AS total_chamado
            FROM chamado, cliente
            WHERE chamado.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente
            GROUP BY chamado.id_cliente) AS total_chamado 
ON cli.id_cliente = total_chamado.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN (SELECT cliente.id_cliente, COUNT(*) AS total_chamado_passado
           FROM chamado, cliente
           WHERE chamado.id_cliente = cliente.id_cliente 
             AND chamado.data_atendimento  BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 month AND CURDATE()
           GROUP BY chamado.id_cliente) AS total_chamado_passado
ON cli.id_cliente = total_chamado_passado.id_cliente
```

O resultado que eu fiz nos testes fica:

```
|id_cliente|total_chamado|total_chamado_passado
|     1    |     3       |         2          |
|     3    |     1       |                    |
|     4    |     1       |                    |
```

o link para a tabela que eu simulei está aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4007/19